# How do I achieve max damage with Doomfist's Seismic Slam?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

The description for Doomfist's *Airstrike* achievement is "*Get a killing blow with Doomfist's full-power Seismic Slam in Quick or Competitive play.*"

I've tried using my slam all across the maps, but I've struggled to find spots high enough to consistently do the maximum 125 damage needed for the achievement. Even when using Rising Uppercut to gain some extra height, I always seem to come up short.

**How can I achieve maximum damage with Doomfist's Seismic Slam?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are specific positions on all maps where he can deal the max damage of 125 from his Seismic Slam.  A [reddit user went fairly in depth with this guide:](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/6qaprv/all_optimal_doomfist_positions_for_a_125_damage/)

> To clarify before we get started: These are positions Doomfist can leap from where he can deal a 125 damage Seismic Slam without needing to be knocked back or slide on a diagonal surface. There are extra positions on certain maps (such as Lijiang Garden) that would be on the list if they didn't require sliding, but these sliding leaps give significantly less freedom as to where you can land.
>
> All Imgur albums are organised with two pictures. The first is looking at the position from somewhere the position can hit, and the second is Doomfist standing in the position.
>
> Unless stated otherwise, all Slams were performed from a standing position. **DO NOT use Rising Uppercut to get extra height!** You will spend less time in the air and deal less damage as a result!
>
> ## Dorado
>
> [This high ground to the right of section B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAVOy.jpg)
>
> ## Eichenwalde
>
> [The highest point of the castle in payload section A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrwA8.jpg)
>
> [This chandelier (you must jump for this one, you will deal 12**4** damage if you do not jump. **DO NOT UPPERCUT**) in payload section B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WrC8.jpg)
>
> ## Hanamura
>
> The three highest positions of high ground on Point B to the lowest ground in front of Point B:
>
> [1: The arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFFT3.jpg)
>    [2: The easiest-access one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeVbi.jpg)
>    [3: The "Widow high ground"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nwbG.jpg)
>
> [The highest point of the choke on Point A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMkJQ.jpg)
>
> [EDIT: The top of this building next to Point A](https://gfycat.com/DependableShimmeringFoxhound)
>
> ## Hollywood
>
> [The catwalk above payload section A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILQC7.jpg)
>
> [The platform under the water tower Torbjorn players almost certainly use at the control point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKAdV.jpg)
>
> ## Horizon Lunar Colony
>
> [This excruciatingly slow moving platform above point B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avml3.jpg)
>
> [IIIIIIIIIN SPAAAAAAAAAAAAAACE (this is the only one where there is not a significant height difference between the starting and ending points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUXeQ.jpg)
>
> ## Ilios: Lighthouse
>
> [This very high ground on the lighthouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLtsJ.jpg)
>
> ## Ilios: Well
>
> [This very high ground on the building next to the well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJvMV.jpg)
>
> ## Ilios: Ruins
>
> [On top of the broken pillars around the point (only provides enough distance if the destination is the control point itself)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs9bQ.jpg)
>
> ## King's Row
>
> [This box on this high ground at the end of payload section B (only provides enough distance if the destination is the payload destination)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hALyc.jpg)
>
> [The head of the Mondatta statue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34AJL.jpg)
>
> [The highest entrance of the attacker spawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1FtN.jpg)
>
> ## Lijiang Night Market
>
> [The highest point of the buildings just outside the spawn rooms (almost completely useless)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpIUL.jpg)
>
> ## Lijiang Garden
>
> Nothing! There is no ground on Lijiang Garden that is both high enough for a 125 damage slam and low enough for Doomfist to reach.
>
> ## Lijiang Control Center
>
> [This high ground overlooking the point (you must jump for this one, you will deal 12**4** damage if you do not jump)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIqtY.jpg)
>
> ## Nepal Village
>
> Nothing! There is no ground on Nepal Village that is both high enough for a 125 damage slam and low enough for Doomfist to reach.
>
> ## Nepal Shrine
>
> Nothing! There is no ground on Nepal Shrine that is both high enough for a 125 damage slam and low enough for Doomfist to reach.
>
> There *is* an elephant statue that *is* high enough to land on the low ground next to the control point with a healthpack on it, but you cannot control the Slam arc enough to actually hit the ground. You just leap off the cliff.
>
> ## Nepal Sanctum
>
> [The top of these buildings outside the spawn rooms (almost completely useless)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abzgZ.jpg)
>
> ## Numbani
>
> Nothing! There is no ground on Numbani that is both high enough for a 125 damage slam and low enough for Doomfist to reach.
>
> Ironic, isn't it? The map where Doomfist wrecked OR-15s in the airport is one of the few that he cannot perform a full-power Seismic Slam in unassisted.
>
> ## Oasis City Centre
>
> Uhh... inside one of the spawn rooms? (this one is so useless I didn't even put it in an imgur album)
>
> [This high ground overlooking the point (this is the most nitpicky one yet. You must both leave the blue railing intact AND jump before starting the Slam if you want to deal 125 damage. If only one of these is true, you will deal 12**4** damage)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH1qI.jpg)
>
> ## Oasis Gardens
>
> [This high ground overlooking the point (the hardest one to get into, as to get up there you have to Uppercut to the hole below it, then run backwards and jump, *then* Uppercut in mid-air to land on the high ground)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TAuF.jpg)
>
> ## Oasis University
>
> Nothing! There is no ground on Oasis University that is both high enough for a 125 damage slam and low enough for Doomfist to reach.
>
> ## Route 66
>
> [The railing on top of "The High Side" building in the middle of section B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X57ri.jpg)
>
> [This rock pillar at the start of section A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSuI1.jpg)
>
> ## Temple of Anubis
>
> [This high ground in front of Point B (very popular Widowmaker spot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Hcp.jpg)
>
> EDIT: [The similar high ground in front of point A (someone found a way up there)](https://gfycat.com/AnguishedFabulousBoubou)
>
> ## Volskaya Industries
>
> [The highest point of this building in front of the attackers' spawn (works in both directions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cvlt.jpg)
>
> [This slightly less high point of the same building (only works Slamming towards the attackers' spawn)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXcVu.jpg)
>
> ## Watchpoint: Gibraltar
>
> The two highest points able to reach the lowest ground on section A
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV5yl.jpg)
>   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhpU6.jpg)
>
> The highest point overlooking the end of section A (I actually forgot to get screenshots of this one, I'm afraid. It's the same high ground as "1" listed eariler, just closer to the end)
>
> [Pretty much the entire shuttle hanging above section B (the absolute front-most point is not high enough, but you don't need to jump from there the shuttle is huge)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPrvO.jpg)
>
> [This orange... thing next to the shuttle (yes i know it's an orange tarp but I don't know what's under it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiNdT.jpg)
>
> [This incredibly high ground overlooking the start of section C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nezqa.jpg)
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> Don't do this on any KOTH maps or Numbani. Always try to do this on Watchpoint: Gibraltar.

Comment: There are wayy too many images and at any rate will turn an already long answer into a nauseatingly longer one. For conciseness, basicallt

Comment: +1, however about Numbani... [OVERRULED!!!](https://postimg.org/image/fabfzip9x/)  I managed to get it from the **railing** of the walkway overlooking the first payload point after capture.  A jump/slam at peak of jump/spin around (then being lucky) to flatten an enemy Doomfist did the trick.  Meant to get that Widowmaker though, but pretty sure I got her shortly after.  I would still agree to not attempt it on this map as it is easier from the others, I only did it there because I was stuck with that map that round.

Comment: [I ended up getting it on Lijang Control Center](https://imgur.com/a/pTlGp). The high point above the control center was by far the simplest. :P

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects some of the media you included in your post since they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you [edit] your post and re-upload the Gfycat media via SE's Imgur instance to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE's Imgur instance. See [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) for more info.